# How to create one table with same datatype of all columns from another table?

Tags: oracle

I have one table and I need to create one dummy table with same column names and data but with different datatypes for some of the columns. 
For example: Table-1 has two columns C1 (varchar2) and C2(date). 
I need to create a dummy table called Table-2 with columns C1 (varchar2) and C2(varchar2).

Please suggest the way to do it in oracle.

Comment: How can you be sure that `varchar2` will handle all the possible types of the starting table? for example, what if you have a `BLOB` field in the starting table?

Comment: Datatypes for the first table is not of concern. I need to create the dummy where I want all columns as varchar2.

Comment: You have to consider the types of the starting table: say you create a table2 with all varchar2 columns; say you have a blob field in table1, when you try to insert data in table2, you'll get an error. So, you have to make some assunptions on the types of the starting table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the columns of the starting table can be converted ( implicit conversion) in `VARCHAR2`, you can do something like the following.
Say you have this table:

```
SQL> create table table1 (
  2      date_field date,
  3      varchar_field varchar2(1000),
  4      number_field number
  5      );

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (sysdate, 'some text', 999);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

You can build a dynamis SQL that creates another table and copies the data from one table to another, using implicit type conversion:

```
SQL> declare
  2      stm varchar2(32767);
  3  begin
  4      select 'create table table2( ' ||
  5             listagg(column_name, ' varchar2(4000), ') within group (order by column_name) ||
  6             ' varchar2(4000) )'
  7      into stm
  8      from user_tab_columns
  9      where table_name = 'TABLE1';
 10      --
 11      execute immediate stm;
 12      --
 13      select 'insert into table2( ' ||
 14             listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_name) ||
 15             ' ) select ' ||
 16             listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_name) ||
 17             ' from table1'
 18      into stm
 19      from user_tab_columns
 20      where table_name = 'TABLE1';
 21      execute immediate stm;
 22  end;
 23  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table2;

DATE_FIELD      NUMBER_FIELD    VARCHAR_FIELD
--------------- --------------- ---------------
27-APR-16       some text       999

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to duplicate the table with `create as select`, without the data, for example -

```
create table Table-2 as select * from Table-1 where 1=0;
```

And then alter the datatypes of the required columns manually like so -

```
alter table Table-2 modify (C2 varchar2);
```

After the column was altered you can push the data from Table-1 into Table-2, using proper conversions. in your example -

```
insert into Table-2 select C1, to_char(C2,'dd-mm-yyyy') from Table-1;
```

Comment: 2 columns are just an example, in the run time I may have 100 columns where I need to change the data type in the dummy table.

Comment: You will still have to do this manually, another way will be to generate the DDL for the table and then changing the datatypes before running the DDL command on the new table, but this will still require you to change every column yourself.